# storing the value from a dynamic textbox into javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

hi i am new to php i hav a form which adds a dynamic table row on a button click i am being able to save it aswell as to retrieve it but the problem comes when i retireve the dynamic row with its data i've created a hidden textbox which stores the counter of rows added but the problem is when i try to store its value into my javascript variable it shows NaN whitout the counter value being stored i cant save the value into my database i am just a newbie so please help me out 
here is my javascript  code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        var jj= document.getElementByName('hh').value;
                        alert(jj);
                        function addRow()
                        {
                            //alert(jj)
                            var tbl = document.getElementById('zimtable');
                            var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                            var iteration = lastRow - 1;
                            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

                            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
                            var el = document.createElement('input');
                            el.type = 'text';
                            el.name = 'zimname_' + jj;
                            el.id = 'zimname_' + jj;
                            el.size = 40;
                            el.maxlength = 40;
                            firstCell.appendChild(el);

                            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
                            var el2 = document.createElement('input');
                            el2.type = 'text';
                            el2.name = 'zimmob_' + jj;
                            el2.id = 'zimmob_' + jj;
                            el2.size = 13;
                            el2.maxlength = 13;
                            secondCell.appendChild(el2);


                            // alert(i);
                            //$('#hh').val(jj); 
                            jj++;
                            makhtab.hh.value=jj;

                             alert(jj);
                        }
                    </script>
```

here is my php code which selects the data n shows the output

```
                    $zim = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `makhzim` WHERE makhcode='$newsid' ORDER BY srno")or die(mysl_error());
                            $ctrzim= 0;
                            while ($zrow = mysql_fetch_array($zim)){
                                 $ctrzim++;
                                       echo"<tr>";
                                        echo "<td><input name='zimname_$ctrzim' type='text'  size='40' maxlength='20' value=$zrow[name] /></td>";
                                        echo "<td><input name='zimmob_$ctrzim'  type='text'   size='13' maxlength='20' value=$zrow[mobile] /></td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                            }echo "</table>";
                            echo "<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='addRow();' /><input id=\"hh\" name=\"hh\" type='hidden' value='$ctrzim'/>";
                            ?>
```

Comment: You have two `alert(jj);`. Which one returns NaN ? Also you have a variable named `makhtab` that i can't find where has been declared!

Comment: well makhtab is my forms id sir

Comment: and yes alert(jj); returns NaN

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
var jj = document.getElementByName('hh').value;
```

to:

```
var jj = document.getElementsByName('hh')[0].value;
```

*Please note:* the function's name is `getElementsByName()`. Note the plural "getElements".

*Updated* jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aazev/Ct76z/

PHP code shown for illustration purposes only.

Comment: but will the hidden value will keep on changing as the user clicks on the add button??

Comment: That line ensures that you're getting the value from the hidden field, so if you store it back after increasing, it should keep changing.

Comment: Check the jsFiddle I just posted please.

Comment: but sir as u can see above the value keeps on changing coz off the php variable $ctr is declared into the hidden textbox

Comment: Yes, but php code is executed on the server, while javascript is executed on the client (browser). So, the actions made in your javascript code will depend, and use, the information php left in your html code.

Comment: it's also good to note that, in the way your javascript seems to be placed (before the <body> tag), the page might not be fully loaded when it executes, so it won't find the 'hh' element. I'd recommend moving the line mentioned above inside your `addRow()` function.

Comment: but the both php code and javascript is executed on the same file sir if u want den i can show u my whole code

Comment: they are both placed inside the same file, but PHP parses your code into html on the server, and sends just HTML to your browser. Only then your javascript will be able to run.

Comment: yes sir so can u please help me i am just a begginner and as u gave me the link it shows var jj = document.getElementsByName('hh')[0].value; but i want the value of $zimctrto be place instead of [0]

Answer (score 0):

Try using document.getelementbyid

```
var hiddenvalue = document.getElementById('hh').value;
```